Issue with type 'this', while used inside a class, being different than the type of the class itself
I have this ugly looking type, which basically just removes methods and makes stack optional:
type SerializedError<T extends Error> = Omit<
  T,
  | Required<{
      [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends CallableFunction ? K : never;
    }>[keyof T]
  | 'stack'
> & {
  stack?: string | undefined;
} extends infer U
  ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] }
  : never;

And I have this custom error class:
export class ApiError extends Error {
  public override stack: string = '';

  public constructor(reason: any) {
    const { name, message, stack } = reason;
    super(typeof message === 'string' ? message : String(reason));
    this.name = typeof name === 'string' ? name : this.constructor.name;
    typeof stack === 'string'
      ? (this.stack = stack)
      : Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }

  public serialize(includeStack: boolean = false): SerializedError<this> {
    const classKeys = Object.keys(this) as (keyof this)[];
    const serializableKeys = classKeys.filter((key) => {
      const isMethod = typeof this[key] === 'function';
      const isStack = key === 'stack';
      return !isMethod && (!isStack || includeStack);
    }) as (keyof SerializedError<this>)[];

    return serializableKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = this[key]; // Type 'keyof SerializedError<this>' cannot be used to index type 'this'
      return acc;
    }, {} as SerializedError<this>);
  }
}

I wanna use SerializedError<this> for ApiError's serialize method, like shown above, so it would work for any class extending ApiError. But typescript doesn't let me to do that as shown in the code snippet comment.
But when I change this with ApiError, error is gone:
public serialize(includeStack: boolean = false): SerializedError<ApiError> {
  const classKeys = Object.keys(this) as (keyof ApiError)[];
  const serializableKeys = classKeys.filter((key) => {
    const isMethod = typeof this[key] === 'function';
    const isStack = key === 'stack';
    return !isMethod && (!isStack || includeStack);
  }) as (keyof SerializedError<ApiError>)[];

  return serializableKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = this[key]; // No error
    return acc;
  }, {} as SerializedError<ApiError>);
}

So the question is why this and ApiError in the given context aren't the same, and is there any way to make it work (maybe with different approach)?

The this object is of the  polymorphic this type, which is essentially a generic subtype of the current class. TS doesn't know what it is exactly until you call a method on it, so complicated conditionals like SerializedError are impenetrable on generics and this. I mean, TS has no idea what SerializedError<this> might be. You should probably just write SerializedError<ApiError> if you don't care about subclassing. If that fully addresses the q I'll write an a or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz If I use ApiError instead of this, the subclasses properties won't be seen. Like if I create something like ClientError that extends ApiError, which gonna have an additional property status, this property won't be in ReturnType<HttpError['serialize']>. Maybe I should just override serialize for each subclass. But yes, this answers why this and ApiError aren't the same in that context.

The only approach that I know of to use both polymorphic this and conditional types is to use type assertions, so just pepper things with as until it works, unfortunately. See the linked q/a above for more information.

It works if I do acc[key] = (this as any)[key];. Or other way around (acc as any)[key] = this[key]; if I remove type assertion of serializableKeys, which is less code.
